# MySQL Select Matching Rows With Same Value From 2 Different Items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns (primary key, Col1, Col2). Col1 has an index on it. The table is over 100 million rows so I want to query using the index for speed.

Im trying to search 2 items from Col1 that have having matching values in Col2 but excluding any results that only match 1 of the items.

```
Col1  | Col2
------------
item1 | 123
item2 | 492
item3 | 123
item4 | 392
item5 | 588
item1 | 456
item2 | 492
item3 | 039
item4 | 938
item5 | 209
item1 | 456
```

So for example this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Col1` = 'item1' OR `Col1` = 'item3' group 
by Col2
having count(*) > 1
```

Returns:

```
item1 | 123
item1 | 456
```

`item1 | 123` is correct since it matches both item1 and item3 like I want but I don't want it to return `item1 | 456` since it doesn't match both item1 and item3. It's only returning because there are 2 item1's that match it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT Col2
FROM `table`
WHERE Col1 IN ('item1', 'item3') 
GROUP BY Col2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Col1) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` instead:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Col2
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Col2
    -- WHERE Col1 IN ('item1', 'item3')
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Col1) = 2
) t2
    ON t1.Col2 = t2.Col2;
```

Note that you need to join your original query back to the main table if you want to return the full matching records.  I also do not make assumptions about which matches you want, but rather return all matching pairs.

### Demo

Comment: How would I search specifically item1 and item3 this way? The table is millions of rows. I could be wrong but im assuming this would return everything that matches not just the 2 items that I am searching.

Comment: @Dan You can add a `WHERE` clause to the subquery.  I tried to give a general answer.